# Removing Spring Beans from Application Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using the below to display all spring beans in the context. How can I remove beans from the context?

```
 ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
 for(String beanName:ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
     System.out.println(beanName);
 }
```

Comment: remove the bean definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ProxyApplication.class, args);
    BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    for(String beanName : ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()){
        System.out.println(beanName);
        registry.removeBeanDefinition(beanName);
    }
```

Comment: Apparently, you can't do it. See this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29267